# Create logical replication along with normal replication

Tags: postgresql, replication, pg-logical

I need to replicate only some of the tables from my Master Postgres.

With Google search, I got to know that it is possible with logical replication from Postgres10.

I already have a read-only replica and now I want to add another replica but with only selected Tables in that new replica.

```
   A--->B(normal replica with all data from A)
(Master)
   |
   |--->C(logical replica with only selected tables from A)
```

How do I configure this?

My master is set to `wal_level = 'hot_standby'`. B is my standby replica.
Now I want to add a new replica C which should contain replicas of only selected tables.

Now, for C if I set `wal_level=logical` this will affect the A-B. The addition of C should not affect the current A-B setup.

Comment: The **master** must be set to `logical`. The WAL level on B or C is pretty much irrelevant for this setup. Your  streaming replication is not affected from logical replication. This is all documented [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html). Note that with 9.6 the level "hot_standby" was removed - it's still accepted, but is the same as `replica`. You shouldn't use `hot_standby` any more